# C++ Doubly Linked List: Creating and Filling List Using Matrix Class Member

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, operator-overloading, doubly-linked-list

Good evening, I'm trying to fill a doubly linked list with a matrix that I created using my Matrix and Dlist classes. It compiles and runs, but when I try to print the list, it seems like things aren't being linked properly. When I call the print function in the main, it just prints blank. Why aren't isn't my list being created/saved during the make_list_util and make_list function call?

my expected out-put should be:

```
1 - 2 - 3 -|x (Null Ptr)
|   |   |
4 - 5 - 6 -|x (Null Ptr)
|   |   |
7 - 8 - 9 -|x (Null Ptr)
```

when I go to print I don't get anything after `IN PRINT:` and I get a segmentation fault at while(dp){.

dlist.h file:

```
    node members:    
        int data;
        node* next;
        node* prev;
        node* up;
        node* down;
    dlist members:
        node* head;
        node* tail;
        int count;
```

function calls from dlist to make list:

```
dlist::dlist()
    : head(NULL), tail(NULL), count(0) {}

dlist::node* dlist::make_list_util(matrix m, int row, int col, node* p) {
    if (row >= 3 || 3 <= col) { 
        return NULL; 
    }
    node* temp = new node(m(row, col));
    temp->prev = p;
    temp->up = p;
    std::cout << "\nIN MAKE LIST BEFORE RECCURSIVE NEXT: " << temp->data << std::endl;  // the values are correct there
    temp->next = make_list_util(m, row, col + 1, p); // Recursive next
    std::cout << "\nIN MAKE LIST BEFORE RECCURSIVE DOWN: " << temp->data << std::endl;  // the values are correct there
    temp->down = make_list_util(m, row + 1, col, p); // Recursive down
    return temp;
}

dlist::node* dlist::make_list(matrix m) {
    return make_list_util(m, 0, 0, NULL);
}

void dlist::print() {
    // Make pointers: right pt, down pt
    node *rp, *dp = head;
    std::cout << "\nIN PRINT: " << dp->data << std::endl;        
while (dp) {          // For some reason the loop won't initiate here
        rp = dp;
        while (rp) {
            std::cout << rp->data;
            rp = rp->next;
            if (rp != NULL) {
                std::cout << " - ";
            }
            else {
                std::cout << " -|x NullPtr";
            }
        }
        std::cout << "|      |      |\n";
        dp = dp->down; 
    }
}
```

main function code:

```
int main() {
    int row(0), col(0);
    matrix m2(3,3);
    dlist l;
    m2 = { {1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9} };

    l.make_list(m2);
    l.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the error is with linking nodes, then there is a lot of unnecessary code here. Try to remove everything that is not related to your problem.

Comment: "_What am I missing?_" - Well ... You expect other people to tell you? Have you read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @cigien: I think that I was able to make it relate more to the question at hand.
Ted Lynngmo: thank you for the link, I have restate the question to better clarify my problem.

Comment: *"It seems like things aren't being linked properly"*. What makes you say that? Show exactly some input, and expected output, and the output the program actually gives. Also, I don't mean you should only delete code. The provided code still needs to be compilable.

Comment: @cigien: the expected output from print would be:
1 2 3
4 5 6
6 7 8
The problem I am having is that when I go to print the data from rp, it isn't printing anything.

Comment: Please add all information to the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on posted code, there are few problems in the logic of calling the function recursively. It doesn't reset col value, when row comes to 2; Try something like this ( not tested, used reference for m). You can replace your code with this one.

```
dlist::node* dlist::make_list_util(matrix& m, /*int row, int col,*/ node* p) {
  if (row >= 3 || 3 <= col) {
    return NULL;
  } 
  node* temp = new node(m(row, col));
  if (p == NULL)
      head = temp;
  temp->prev = p;
  temp->up = p;
  std::cout << "\nIN MAKE LIST BEFORE RECCURSIVE NEXT: " << temp->data << std::endl;
  col++;
  temp->next = make_list_util(m, /*row, col + 1,*/ temp); // Recursive next
  std::cout << "\nIN MAKE LIST BEFORE RECCURSIVE DOWN: " << temp->data << std::endl;
  col = 0;
  if (row < 2) {
    row++;
    temp->down = make_list_util(m, /*row + 1, col,*/ p); // Recursive down
  }
  return temp;
}
```

Also note, that the call to l.make_list(m2) returns the head of the list, but you are not using it in the call to l.print();  You can try this

```
  //l.make_list(m2);
  l.print(l.make_list(m2) );
```

I also suggest to use reference for parameter matrix, not use it by value, in the function calls:

```
     node* make_list_util(matrix&, /*int row, int col,*/ node* );
     node* make_list(matrix& );
```

to avoid constructing it. Not sure why you use 4 pointers for doubly linked list, as two is enough per node. Probably there is an error in their usage too. The debugger is your best friend here to find out what's not set properly.